# XML loader not processing XML correctly

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, loader

I have researched this topic and I believe the answer is [AS3 Scope Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877740/as3-scope-issue) though I can not resolve the issue.

My xml loads fine and I can traverse it fine. I need to compare it against an array in another file so I believe the best thing to do is put then node I want into a class variable/field.

My xml:

```
<Test>
<coordinates>
         -82.4055872666786,35.6963112340393,0
   </coordinates>
</Test>
```

My main class is:

```
private var getTheNode:String;


    public function Tiles(){
        try{
        _xmlLoader = new XmlLoader("368.xml");
        trace("loaded: ");
        } catch(e:Error){
            trace("couldn't load XML file")
        }
trace(getTheNode);

        _xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onXmlReady);         
    }
```

The xmlLoader is:

```
public function XmlLoader(path:String){
        _loader = new URLLoader();
        try{
        _loader.load(new URLRequest(path));
        }catch(e:Error){
            trace("error in loading the XML file")
        }
        _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoadXml);
    }

    private function onLoadXml(event:Event):void{
        _xml = XML(URLLoader(event.target).data)
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
    }
```

Seems easy enough but I keep getting null or undefined depending on the twist I try.

When I do a trace on getTheNode inside function all is well but the trace inside constructor turns up null.

I could post the code that gets the node inside the onLoadXml but that is what I am trying to figure out...if it traces inside the function wouldn't/shouldn't it update the class field if my listeners are setup correctly?

Thanks,
Terry

Comment: What are you tracing that gives null or undefined? Add some more details

Comment: Well I will have to read up on instructions to place additional code in this comment section but let's I am in the onXmlReady function and I have node called Test and Test has a node called Test1. I can put a trace in this function and trace either Test or Test->Test1.

Comment: Don't post additional code in the comments - just edit your question! Do post some of your xml as well, though.  It might be a parsing issue.

Comment: try changing this _xml = XML(URLLoader(event.target).data)
 to _xml = XML(event.target.data) or if you insist on type casting the event target _xml = XML((event.target as URLLoader).data)

Comment: if that doesn't do it try trace(event.target.data) and see what the server is sending back I have a feeling your server code is generating an error code response which is not the XML structure you are looking for.

Comment: Will try all of above. FYI, server taken out of loop pulling in the xml straight up. Thanks.

Comment: _xml = XML(event.target.data) did not work. trace(event.target.data) in onLoadXml traces out xml tree like I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to leave a comment, sorry.  So, two things. First off, if your XML document has a namespace - something like xmlns:"http://urlhere.com", it could be causing your troubles.  [Here's](http://archive.darronschall.com/weblog/2006/04/using-xml-namespaces-with-e4x-and-actionscript-3.html) a simple example.

Also, you should add an IOError listener to you URLLoader, as you can see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary).

Comment: Just a FYI you need a higher rep to post comments I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Ok since you stated in the comments that you are getting the data from trace(event.target.data) it leads me to believe you are not parsing your xml properly.

First your xml needs to be changed a little. Good practice to call the root node root.
And remember the root node is not referenced at all when you are parsing the XML.

```
var myXML:XML = new XML(
  <root>
    <coordinate>
      -100.123456789,35.1213456789,0
    </coordinate>
  </root>
);
trace("coords->" + myXML.coordinate );
```

As you can see I added another coord. Just for example purposes.
The root node is not accessible.

So lets expand a little and add more coords.

```
var myXML:XML = new XML(
<root>
  <coordinates>
    <coordinate id="1">
      -82.4055872666786,35.6963112340393,0
    </coordinate>
    <coordinate id="2">
      -100.123456789,35.1213456789,0
    </coordinate>
  </coordinates>
</root>
);
var myCoordCollection:XMLListCollection =  new XMLListCollection( myXML.coordinates.coordinate )
for each( var item:Object in myCoordCollection){
   trace( "id->" +item.@id + "    coords->" + item );
}
```

There is also the e4x methods of parsing but I'm not getting into that now.
Hope this helps you understand XML parsing a little bit more.

Comment: Not sure how you react to someone that is trying to help while rep goes up (below). Will read up.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Just using AS3. I believe this is a event issue. If it were a parsing issue I should be able to trace the entire tree.

Comment: this: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031091/getting-data-from-custom-classes-an-oop-question`   ->If the load method loads the playlist immediately (before you attach your handler), it will have nobody to notify that something happened. In that case, you would attach your handler, but would never receive the event. Luckily, in this particular case, loading is a background async operation which usually takes more time to execute, so your handler gets attached in time  seems to be the problem the solution is another thing.